# Escaping ampersand (&) in URL in Bash under WSL

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm trying to write a Bash function which will take some arguments from the command line and put them in a URL which contains URL parameters (i.e. contains `?` and `&`).

If there is only one parameter in the URL, there is no `&`, and there is no problem, i.e., if I define the following function:

```
test() {
    cmd.exe /c start https://example.com/\?foo=$1
}
```

and invoke it with `test bar`, it opens the URL `https://example.com/?foo=bar` in my browser, which is completely correct.

The problem is when I want to add a second URL parameter. I then extend the function as follows:

```
test() {
    cmd.exe /c start https://example.com/\?foo=$1\&baz=$2
}
```

but when I invoke it with `test bar qux`, the same URL as before (`https://example.com/?foo=bar`) is opened in my browser, and my terminal displays the error `'baz' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

Wrapping the URL in double quotes also does not help: when I change it to

```
test() {
    cmd.exe /c start "https://example.com/\?foo=$1\&baz=$2"
}
```

it opens the URL `https://example.com//?foo=bar"`, and I still get the error `'baz' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `cmd.exe` is invoked with a command, the [`cmd.exe` escape syntax](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html) needs to be used, rather than the Bash escape syntax, i.e. `&` needs to be escaped as `^&` (and `?` does not need escaping). The following works as intended:

```
test() {
    cmd.exe /c start "https://example.com/?foo=$1^&baz=$2"
}
```

(Note that `'baz' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.` is an error generated by `cmd.exe`: it refers to a batch file, which is a Windows concept.)